# How to prove $\int_{A\cup F^{-1}(B)} p(x;\xi)dx =\int_{B}Pr (A|y;\xi)q(y;\xi)$?

Tags: probability, information-theory, information-geometry

I am going through section 2.2 of Methods of Information Geometry by Amari & Nagaoka.I was trying to prove

$\int_{A\cup F^{-1}(B)} p(x;\xi)dx =\int_{B}Pr (A|y;\xi)q(y;\xi)dy$.

[image]

But I was getting

$\int_{A\cup F^{-1}(B)} p(x;\xi)dx =\int_{B}Pr (A\cup F^{-1}(B)|y;\xi)q(y;\xi)dy$

Here is my approach, I will be thankful if someone tells me what I am doing wrong or missing something

[image]

Comment: Hint: note that no matter what $A$ is, for $y \in B,$ $P(X \in A \cap (F^{-1}(B))^c|y) = 0$ (why?).

Comment: Thanks. The reason for this is $F(x)=y$ so $A\cap (F^{-1}(B))^c=\{x\in A : F(x)\neq y\}$.Therefore $Pr((A\cap (F^{-1}(B))^c)\vert y $) gives the probability of the event $F(x)\neq y$ given that $F(x)=$y which is zero in probability.After that result is easy to show. Am I correct?